# I want users to upload an image and view it, move it and resize it inside a 600px x 800px container w/ a static bkg image

Tags: jquery, css, file-upload, html5-canvas

I'd also like the user to delete the image. This is for a design center where users can get a sneak peek at what their logo would look like on top of 2d images of bottles & tubes for hair products. I've tried two versions and have failed at merging all features. I've been able to get either the resize & move aspects with the file upload image not viewable OR the file upload with the image displaying in the container correctly, but without resize/move abilities. I'd appreciate any help on this :-)

[http://jsfiddle.net/carolynrue/9mbcwtyh/](http://jsfiddle.net/carolynrue/eed5o2q0/4/)

```
    <script async src="//http://jsfiddle.net/carolynrue/eed5o2q0/4/embed/"></script>
```

this version is what I based mine on:     https://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

Comment: This version attempts to resize and move the image http://jsfiddle.net/carolynrue/eed5o2q0/4/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance Archer :-)

Comment: Are you trying to use plugin to achieve move/resize etc.? If so, which?

Comment: Using canvas for resize and move. Right now, only resize isn't working.<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/carolynrue/x8dv4zkf/8/embed/"></script>